# Why can 'let' be re-declared in the devtools console in Chrome? (Other browsers don’t allow it.)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, variable-declaration, google-chrome-console

I'm learning about the alternate variable declarations introduced in ES6. Right now, I have learned that the 'let' variable declaration is block scoped, and although it can be updated, it cannot be re-declared in the same scope.

**My first question is:** Is the above information true? I am reading an article from April 2, 2020. Things may have changed.

**My second question is:** If the above information is true, then how come in my Chrome console, when I run

```
let greeting = 'hello';
```

and the following line I re-declare it such as

```
let greeting = 'say hi now';
```

the value is changed to *'say hi now'* and no error is reported.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the semicolon at the end of the line, but not sure. Just a JS noobie here. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you imagine that the same variable name could be made to hold more than one value?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Running those two lines of code in my console (Chrome), I get _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'greeting' has already been declared"_. Running it in the Node REPL (13.7.0), I get _"Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'greeting' has already been declared"_. What _console_ are you running it in?

Comment: What console? Browser consoles and Node REPL are not quite the same as running continuous code "normally."

Comment: FWIW it throws an error in Chrome console if you copy-paste both lines at the same time but not if you run the lines separately.

Comment: @Phil, the error only shows when pasting **both** lines together, when placing separate, no errors are shown.

Comment: In Safari console even running them consecutively throws a duplicate error.

Comment: @0stone0 that's a fair callout. Firefox behaves as expected too (throws an error). Edge behaves like Chrome

Comment: Hey all. I was running it in chrome. Indeed the error appears upon pasting those two lines, but apparently chrome allows let re-declarations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [Google Chrome specific feature](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/12/devtools#redeclarations)

> #### Support for let and class redeclarations in the Console
>
> The Console now supports redeclarations of `let` and `class` statements. The inability to redeclare was a common annoyance for web developers who use the Console to experiment with new JavaScript code.

In experimenting, I found that IE 11 and Edge behave the same as Chrome in that typing each command separately produces no error but executing both in a single evaluation does.

See also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1004193

---

Other experiments show that Firefox and the NodeJS REPL do not offer such a feature.

Comment: Yep I'm running it in chrome. This is the type of info I'd hope to receive in asking this question. Marked as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: @nick_rinaldi no problems. It's a shame you copped a bunch of downvotes initially. I don't think people fully understood what you were asking unfortunately

Comment: It's expected. I tried my best to explain it as thoroughly as possible, but I figured I could always do a better job.