# Error when redeclaring class in Firefox console but not in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, class, declare

```
class Picture {
    constructor(icon) {
        this.icon = icon

    }
}
```

When I run this code twice in the Chrome console it doesn't throw any errors.
But when I try running it twice in the Firefox console it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let Picture`. Why do the browsers behave differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class can't be redefined. It is actually a block scoped variable.

> If you're experimenting with code in a web browser, such as the Firefox Web Console (Tools > Web Developer > Web Console) and you 'Run' a definition of a class with the same name twice, you'll get a SyntaxError: redeclaration of let ClassName;

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#re-running_a_class_definition)

Redeclaration of `let/const` is allowed in chrome console. Run the below statement twice:

```
let x = 2;
```

[Check this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64582489/why-can-let-be-re-declared-in-the-devtools-console-in-chrome-other-browsers) and this link from [Chrome blog](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-80/#redeclarations)

**Redeclaration within the same console line is not allowed though.**